# how to debug error 500 Internal Server Error on an Azure App?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I got an "500 Internal Server Error - An error occurred while starting the application" after deploying my application: https://iidapp.azurewebsites.net/

I keep finding the following error message but I am unable to find out on msdn websites any information describing how I can **specify the SAS URL**

INFO: The app was working for a long period and I didn't have to set the SAS URL; I wonder why suddenly Azure is generating exceptions

INFO2: the app works perfectly on my local machine

Any help is welcomed as I couldn't find any solution by reading the related topics on stackoverflow

```
2017-04-05T18:51:32
System.ApplicationException: The trace listener AzureBlobTraceListener is disabled. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The SAS URL for the cloud storage account is not specified. Use the environment variable 'DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL' to define it.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.RefreshConfig()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Seems like Azure Web App is having some issues right now:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/status/

Comment: Did a quick search on the error and found this link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/413. Please see if the resolution provided there fixes your issue.

Comment: @GauravMantri I tried to delete the content of wwwroot yesterday and it DID NOT address the issue.

Comment: @KoolAid I started to receive the 500 error 20 hours ago

I deployed the same app on another zone and the 500 Error remains :-(

Comment: @Abdelkrim Hmm, definitely weird but since it works locally it may be part of the issue. It only mentions North Europe on that status page but it looks like Web Apps are having issues all across the Americas and APAC.

Comment: @Abdelkrim Can you try again? The errors look like they've cleared from all regions except North Europe

Comment: This is quoted from AzureStatus page. "Starting at approximately 10:20 UTC on 06 Apr 2017, a limited number of customers using App Service \ Web Apps in North Europe may receive HTTP 5xx errors, timeouts or experience high latency when accessing Web Apps deployments hosted in this region. Engineers are exploring mitigation options to restore the health of a back end service responsible for servicing incoming requests. The next update will be provided in 60 minutes, or as events warrant."

Comment: @KoolAid I have DEPLOYED the app in areas that ARE NOT IMPACTED BY THE ISSUE and the APP DOES NOT WORK neither - http://iidapp.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score -1):

1. An error was triggered by W3SVC-WP : {app name}
   **02000780** [image: Observe-Analyze-Mitigate]
2. I found out on [eventid](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-2276-source-Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WMSVC-eventno-10703-phase-1.htm) that the code **02000780** meant that a file was missing
3. I eventually found out that it was possible to log further information by **enabling the stdoulog** inside the **web.config**. Read [When a .NET Core Azure App Service won’t start: 502.5 Process Failure](https://stackify.com/net-core-azure-app-service-wont-start)
4. I opened the debug console and found out that a directory wasn't found https://{app_id}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

Voilà! I corrected the code and the app is up and running!